# Using Iferror function in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel sheet with data as below

---

name/date -- 1-jul -- 2-jul -- 3-jul -- 4-jul -- 5-jul

John ---------      good  -- poor -  good -  good -  good

Adam --------      #N/A --  #N/A  - poor -  poor -  good

mark ---------      #N/A  -- good  - poor  - poor -  good

---

and i want to create another sheet to take the initial value per each row,and neglect the #N/A values as below:

---

name/date -- initial

John ---------      good

Adam --------      poor

mark ---------      good

---

anyway i can achieve that with Iferror?

thanks ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IFERROR() function will not be useful in achieving your goal here.

The following assumes that your data start in column 1, row 2 of the source worksheet.

On your second worksheet in the column where you want to report the first value other than #N/A for a source row, simply *array enter* the following formula in one cell:

```
=INDEX(B2:Z2,,MATCH(FALSE,ISNA(B2:Z2),0))
```

Now copy that formula downward as far as you need.

Note that I've arbitrarily chosen column Z as the column to end the search. You can adjust the Z references in the above formula to suit your needs.

To retrieve the first column values (the names like John, Adam, Mark) a separate formula (normal, not an array formula) can be used:

```
=B1
```

And it can likewise be copied downward as far as you need.